# What do I need to know in order to understand indeterminate forms and L'Hopital's Rule?

Tags: calculus

I'm taking up Calculus right now and I'm having a hard time grasping indeterminate forms and L'Hopital's Rule. I think it's because of my poor background. The previous math subject I took before this was three years ago, and now I'm hazy with all the fundamental ideas that I should have in order to understand these concepts. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: The right direction is the direction that leads to the office of your Calculus teacher, who is paid to answer questions exactly like the one you have just posted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know derivatives: [here's an introduction](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DerivativeIntro.aspx)

Read about indeterminate forms [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LHospitalsRule.aspx)

Comment: The second link lacks an 'x' in the end, but thanks. :)